# Динамическое освещение 2D сцены

Tags: разработка-игр, движок, освещение, raytracing

Доброго времени суток.

**С чем имею дело:** делаю 2D игру с бесконечным процедурно-генерируемым миром. Мир полностью разрушаем. Вид в игре - сверху, как в don't starve. Камера фиксирована, менять её ракурс нельзя. Игра разрабатывается на собственном движке, который я сейчас и пишу.

**Задача:** сейчас работаю над освещением. Необходимо сделать следующее: тени должны иметь правильную геометрическую форму, объекты отбрасывающие тень анимированы и тени должны меняться вместе с анимацией объекта, в игре присутствует динамическая плавная смена времени суток и в течении дня и ночи тени должны менять угол падения и длину. Это то, что необходимо добавить в данный момент.

При реализации надо учитывать, что в будущем мне придется добавить прозрачные и полупрозрачные объекты, отражающие поверхности с разной степенью "отражения"(вода, зеркало, цветное стекло  и т.д.), рассеивание света,  помимо глобального освещение появится освещение от нескольких источников света которые могут двигаться, свет и тени от дрожащих источников света(например костра). 
Короче говоря, мне нужно физически корректное освещение.

**Какой подход я выбрал для решения задачи:** чтобы убить всех зайцев одним выстрелом я выбрал ray traysing.

**Что непонятно:** до того как я стал реализовывать освещение, я рисовал все спрайтами. У меня была регулярная сетка хранящая наборы спрайтов в каждой ячейке, в каждом кадре я выбирал ячейки попадающие на экран, сортировал в них спрайты и выводил сверху вниз. Но прочитав несколько статей по ray traysing,  я пришёл к выводу что эта штука предназначена и работает только с 3D моделями. И вот у меня возникло несколько вопросов, на которые я прошу вас ответить:

1. возможно я ошибся и ray traysing возможно применять и к спрайтам?
2. если ray traysing можно применять только к 3D моделям, то мне придется описать каждое изображение в виде 3D модели. Однако физику мне хотелось бы оставить в 2D. Будут ли от такого решения проблемы? Или если я решил использовать ray traysing, то мне придется полностью переходить к 3D(пусть и упрощенному)?

Comment: Ray tracing, это всего навсего физика, вы её можете прикрутить и к 2D спрайтам. [пруф](https://forums.tigsource.com/index.php?topic=25273.0)

Comment: @B1aZe, если я правильно понял информацию по приведенной вами ссылке, то помимо 2D спрайтов автор также использует карты нормалей для каждого спрайта. Однако у автора камера направлена строго вниз и я не совсем понимаю как это применить, если камера имеет вид как, например, в don't starve, stardew valley, undertale и т.д. Если вам не сложно, могли бы вы объяснить.

Comment: автор видео, использует источник освещения, который не прикреплён к положению камеры, то есть, в не зависимости от того, куда будет смотреть камера, физика теней будет просчитана по своему. Единственное, что придётся заморочится с картой нормалей, для каждого объекта, который будет отбрасывает тень.

Comment: @B1aZe, а разве карта нормалей может использоваться для просчета отбрасываемой тени? Немогли бы вы объяснить в кратце как это работает или скинуть ссылку где об этом можно почитать. Просто во всей инф. которую я нашел о картах нормалей говорится как её использовать для освещения самого объекта чтобы придать ему объемность, но не говорится как с помощью неё рассчитать отбрасываемые тени.

Comment: вы меня не правильно поняли, я лишь написал, что заморочится придётся с самими картами.